# Using strategy pattern with simple factory

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

I've been learning about design patterns and I think I'm a little bit stuck with an exercise where I do not posses any answer-pages to.

I already used the strategy pattern to create this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITO4G.png (minus the setBehavior functions in duck)

I need to improve this design with **simple factory** because at the moment, the 2 types of behaviors are instantiated via following code (shown via example):

```
    public MallardDuck()
    { 
    setQuackBehavior(new Quack());
    setFlyBehavior(new FlyWithWings());
    }
```

This is not correct because we need to program to an interface and not to an implementation.

What I thought to do is making 2 *separate* factories that each handle a specific behavior but when I made the design I started doubting my solution. Is it normal to do this sort of thing with simple factory?

Could anyone push me in the correct direction? :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're programming Ducks, then it's a toy example anyway. Go ahead and do the two separate simple factories. The general rule is a simple factory per interface. You could put all the simple factories in one class to make it less complex.

The disadvantage of concrete classes instantiating other concrete classes is of course the risky coupling to implementations. If the implementation details change (yes, the new is trivial but the whole ducks example is trivial), your classes that know that information are also liable to change.

You're right that it's not programming to an interface. Classes that know less about implementation details are more insulated from changes in those details, which is the whole point of using interfaces.

Comment: "Programming to an interface " is for protecting clients of the class from implementation internal and changes about it.
MallardDuck is not a class offered to the client, it looks like more a concrete client class. So why the client class  should hide the implementation it uses in its implementation ? 
If no reason, it's creating complexity for creating complexity.
For example, in GOF, strategy sample code is like that :
quick = new Composition(new SimpleCompositor())
quick = new Composition(new TextCompositor())
 where xxxCompositor is the strategy class.
So, could you explain me why ?

Comment: I agree with you @davidhxxx if there is one distinct external set of client classes. I saw mallard ducks as clients to quack and fly behaviors. This is the problem with toy examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the strong coupling between concrete strategies and their host you may rely on a factory that knows how to instantiate a Duck with the proper strategies for a given type rater than having a concrete class per type.

The above design may be slightly more testable, but I do not think you should be too concerned about the coupling between concrete ducks and the concrete strategies they use.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not correct because we need to program to an interface and not to an implementation.

And you program to an interface since setQuackBehavior() takes as input an interface and that your quack class represents the quack behavior field as an interface and not an implementation.
At a time, in a code, using a implementation class is normal.
Using a factory with methods returning based interface instances is useful in many cases but in your case, I don't see the interest. Why your quack subclasses should not know which concrete behavior used ? 
If it has no reason, so it seems ok :

```
setQuackBehavior(new Quack());
```

Using factory with not added value gives a complex code without reasons.